# Problem xarray.apply_ufunc on a groupby objects (missing output_dtypes)

Tags: numpy, sorting, dask, python-xarray, numpy-ufunc

I am trying to use xarray.apply_ufunc on the groupby object with dask parallelization but getting error.

Dataset contains daily temperatural data of 30 years over certain location with 1km² grid. So the data shape is 10950x1450x900 (days, Y axis and X axis respectively).

**Main goal is to sort values for each location and for each year. And more importantly algorithm must be memory efficient**

Since data is huge (~120gb) and does not fit into memory, I am trying to sort using `dask`, but from my research I see that there's no simple solution with dask, nor with any other known libs (xarray, numpy...) (if there is any at all)

`dask` does not implement any sorting algorithm since its very complex for parallelization and etc...

Only function `dask` gives us is `topk` method, which returns 0 to N-th element from sorted. When applied on whole dataset memory gets 100%.

So, now I am trying to run `numpy.sort` with `dask` parallelization enabled to see if this could help. But I am not able to even test it, since it throws error.

code used:

```
xarray.apply_ufunc(numpy.sort, dataset.groupby('time.year'), kwargs={'axis': 0}, dask='parallelized', output_dtypes=[numpy.float64])
```

error:

> ValueError: output dtypes (output_dtypes) must be supplied to apply_func when using dask='parallelized'

Am I doing something wrong or `apply_ufunc` does not support `groupby` objects?

from the xarray's [docs](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.apply_ufunc.html) args could be groups too

> *args (Dataset, DataArray, **GroupBy**, Variable, numpy.ndarray, dask.array.Array or scalar) – Mix of labeled and/or unlabeled arrays to which to apply the function.

I am confused how to correctly use it.

Anyway, would be grateful if you suggest any working way.

Comment: Please show a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please let me know what else could I show.

Comment: > …Complete – Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the question itself

Comment: I need some way to do sorting of whole dataset across time dimension. But as I guess there's no way to do it